# How do you align columns in C

Tags: c, text

Im assigned with aligning columns but when I go to compile it, its misaligned here's an example of what I have:

```
printf("column1\tcolumn2\cloumn3");
printf("%-3d%5d%-4d\n", c1,c2,c3);
etc.
```

This is a sample of what I get:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
|5  |    5|5   |
|4  |    4|4   |
|3  |    3|3   |
|2  |    2|2   |
```

How would I go about aligning them? They also must be left justified by 3, right by 5 and left by 4.

Comment: The computer is printing exactly what you told it to print, what's the problem here?

Comment: I want them to align under their column rather then having the things in column 3 being in column 2.

Comment: In that case, you can't have a column width of 3 because `Column1` is longer than `3`.  You need the columns to be at least as wide as the heading or the maximum value in it.  You have to give up one or the other — or split the column heading forcibly at the appropriate width and print it over multiple lines (`Col` plus `umn` plus `1` — ick!).

Comment: The alignment values you are using match what you describe.  If you want the _fields_ to be aligned, then you need to add spaces (or a variable length field and parameter).  I would recommend a thorough reading of the printf documentation.

Also, your code doesn't match the output.  Where are the vertical bars (pipes) coming from?

Comment: Please tell me how you want the word "Column1" to fit in 3 spaces??

Comment: I cant tell you i was told to do this: The hours column should occupy
3 spaces and the values should be left justified. The minutes column should occupy 5 spaces and the values should be right justified. The seconds column should occupy 4 spaces and the values should be left justified. Just switch column1,2,3 with hours minutes seconds

Comment: There are three possibilities: you can omit the headings, fold the headings, or perform a miracle. You need to clarify which of the three you are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

> They also must be left justified by 3, right by 5 and left by 4

Values 3,5,4 are insufficient to align with column headers like `"Column1"`, etc.. [@Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104097/how-do-you-align-columns-in-c/42104218#comment71378143_42104097)

---

Use a common width via a *print width specifier* for each column and `printf()` format.

Easy to adjust as needed, once the 3,5,4 insufficiency figured out.

```
int w[3] = {8,8,8};  // Adjust as desired
printf("|%*s|%*s|%*s|\n", w[0], "column1", w[1], "column2", w[2], "column3");
printf("|%-*d|%*d|%-*d|\n", w[0], c1, w[1], c2, w[2], c3);
```

Sample

```
| column1| column2| column3|
|1       |       2|3       |
```